# How to get rid of excess blank space in CSS slideshow without getting rid of manual button transition?

Tags: html, css

I have a slideshow made of pure CSS3. It will stay only CSS, no JS at all. It automatically slides after 5 seconds (using animation), back and forth between the two images it holds. The user can also manually click a button to cause a slide (using transition). The div for the two images is as long as they are. My problem is that if the slideshow automatically slides to the second image and the user clicks the button for that second image, it'll slide again to an empty space with no image in place. How can I stop it from sliding again on the second image button click after automatic slide to that second image?

CSS:

```
.slideshowcontainer {
    width: 800px;
    height: 400px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    top: 30px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 10px;
    border-color: white;
    border-radius: 15px;
}

.imagecontainer {
    width: 1800px;
    height: 400px;
    clear: both;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transition: left 3s;
    -moz-transition: left 3s;
    -o-transition: left 3s;
    -ms-transition: left 3s;
    transition: left 3s;
    animation: scroller 16s infinite;
}

@keyframes scroller {
    0% {
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
    31.25% {
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
    50% {
        transform: translateX(-800px);
    }
    81.25% {
        transform: translateX(-800px);
    }
    100% {
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
}

.slideshowimage {
    float: left;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    position: relative;
}


#slideshowimage-1:target ~ .imagecontainer {
animation: none;
transform: translateX(0px);
}

#slideshowimage-2:target ~ .imagecontainer {
animation: none;
transform: translateX(-800px);
}

.buttoncontainer {
    position: relative;
    top: -20px;
}

.button {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: darkgray;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 0.25s;
    -moz-transition: background-color 0.25s;
    -o-transition: background-color 0.25s;
    -ms-transition: background-color 0.25s;
    transition: background-color 0.25s;
}

.button:hover {
    background-color: gray;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="slideshowcontainer">
    <span id="slideshowimage-1"></span>
    <span id="slideshowimage-2"></span>
    <span id="slideshowimage-3"></span>
        <div class="imagecontainer">
            <a href="#"><img src="WebServiceSlide.png" class="slideshowimage" style="width:800px;height:400px;"></a>
            <a href="#"><img src="es-flag.png" class="slideshowimage" style="width:800px;height:400px;"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="buttoncontainer">
            <a href="#slideshowimage-1" class="button"></a>
            <a href="#slideshowimage-2" class="button"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Problem 1, `.imagecontainer ` is never a sibling of `slideshowimage-1` or `slideshowimage-2`. [They must have a common parenet](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the button gets clicked you have switch the **animation off** and make the **translation**

I have added the code snippet

```css
.slideshowcontainer {
    width: 800px;
    height: 400px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    top: 30px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 10px;
    border-color: white;
    border-radius: 15px;
}

.imagecontainer {
    width: 1800px;
    height: 400px;
    clear: both;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transition: all 3s;
    -moz-transition: all 3s;
    -o-transition: all 3s;
    -ms-transition: all 3s;
    transition: all 3s;
    transform: translateX(0px);
    animation: scroller 16s infinite;
}

@keyframes scroller {
    0% {
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
    31.25% {
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
    50% {
        transform: translateX(-800px);
    }
    81.25% {
        transform: translateX(-800px);
    }
    100% {
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
}

.slideshowimage {
    float: left;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    position: relative;
}

#slideshowimage-1:target ~ .imagecontainer {
    animation: none;
    transform: translateX(0px);
}

#slideshowimage-2:target ~ .imagecontainer {
    animation: none;
    transform: translateX(-800px);
}

.buttoncontainer {
    position: relative;
    top: -20px;
}

.button {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: darkgray;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 0.25s;
    -moz-transition: background-color 0.25s;
    -o-transition: background-color 0.25s;
    -ms-transition: background-color 0.25s;
    transition: background-color 0.25s;
}

.button:hover {
    background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="slideshowcontainer">
    <span id="slideshowimage-1"></span>
    <span id="slideshowimage-2"></span>
    <span id="slideshowimage-3"></span>
        <div class="imagecontainer">
            <a href="#"><img src="https://www.internetcreation.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/banner-web-design.png" class="slideshowimage" style="width:800px;height:400px;"></a>
            <a href="#"><img src="http://23k8dv4brsbv18vf5lh7gb21.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/banner-web-development.png" class="slideshowimage" style="width:800px;height:400px;"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="buttoncontainer">
            <a href="#slideshowimage-1" class="button"></a>
            <a href="#slideshowimage-2" class="button"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks but the issue here is that once the user clicks a button, they slideshow will no longer automatically play from then on. They press the button and it slides, but there is no automatic animation after another 5 seconds. How could I have it so that they click and it transitions correctly (as you explained), but with the continuation of the automatic sliding?

Comment: yaah... its because of css limitations. translate doesn't work unless you stop animating(wont work even if you assign new animation). i have tried some other tricks also.but I cant assign animation within keyframes (that is also a limitation). so this is my best scoop of ice-cream. accept and upvote if it is usefull